# Jenkins: Nunit tests doesn't appears in SonarQube

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jenkins, sonarqube, nunit

We have a C# solution, and a CI solution with jenkins.

Every night, jenkins clears it workspace, get the latest version, build it in debug, run the tests through `OpenCover`.

We have the following builds steps(I'm not mentionning the steps before):

1. SonarQube Begin

First things we do in jenkins is the "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis", we specifiy the project key/name and the additional arguments:

```
/d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="%CD%\TestResult.xml"
/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="%CD%\opencover.xml"
```

2. Build

We use the MSBUILD14 to build or solution in debug

3. Execute tests through OpenCover

We use openCover to check the code coverage and execute the tests:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -filter:"+[*]* -[*.Test]*" -output:"%CD%\opencover.xml" -threshold:1 -register:User -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"Solution\MySolution.sln --config=Debug --result=%CD%\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2"
exit 0
```

4. SonarQube end Analysis

This should publish the results of the SonarQube Results

5. PostBuild: Publish NUnit test result report

I've an additional steps that should publish the TestResult.xml with the following argument:

```
%CD%\TestResult.xml
```

Once the whole job is done, I've in sonarqube, the static analysis result, but I DON'T have the Unit tests results and the code coverage results.

I've checked the logs, the tests have been executed:

```
Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 4331, Passed: 3819, Failed: 189, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 323
    Failed Tests - Failures: 39, Errors: 147, Invalid: 3
    Skipped Tests - Ignored: 323, Explicit: 0, Other: 0
  Start time: 2017-02-07 10:03:42Z
    End time: 2017-02-07 11:51:56Z
    Duration: 6494.182 seconds
```

I only have one weird exception:

```
An System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException occured: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ActivationException.cs'. 
An System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException occured: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocator.cs'. 
An System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException occured: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs'. 
An System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException occured: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs'.
```

Which happens at the end of openCover step. The 2 XML files are still generated, and I also have this exception locally.

Any idea why I don't have the code coverage/unit tests results in sonarQube?

Thank you!

Comment: I am also facing the same error, did you find the solution?

Comment: @pawanplus I unfortunately don't remember how we fixed it, but I think we installed more recent versions of sonarqube runner and NUNIT

Comment: Thanks @J4N, I already have latest versions. NVM I'll check and post when  I'll get answer.

Comment: Got it working by applying filter in the opencover command.

Comment: @pawanplus I am stuck with the same issue! What filter did you use ?

Comment: @jBravo try adding `-filter:"+[*]* -[Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation]*"` this at the end of open cover command

Comment: @pawanplus I already had a filter. I tryed yours but it didn't save me neither. Thanks you anyway!